# Differential Drive Controller 'enable_odom_tf: false' doesn't work

Tags: odometry, sensor-fusion, diff-drive-controller, ros2-control, ros2-controllers

I have 2 wheels diff_drive robot that use diff_drive_controller from ros2_control,so this first work as diff_cont (diff_drive_controller name) publish transform from odom to base_link on /tf.

Now I want to add IMU with robot_localization package,so this will receive odom data from diff_cont and imu data from IMU and publish on /tf odom to base_link.

The problem is it seems like that ekf_node publish on /tf and diff_cont publish on /tf too cause the robot to jiggle between odometry from efk_node and diff_cont node(My apology if this confuse you.I'm trying to say that when I open Rviz2 with Odometry, there are 2 odometry topics)

How can this be fix? I set the parameter `enable_odom_tf: false` but diff_cont still publish on /tf,I even check that after I launch the robot `enable_odom_tf` is False by `ros2 get /diff_cont enable_odom_tf`.

This is my params file my_controllers.yaml

```yaml
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    #use_sim_time: true

    diff_cont:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

    joint_broad:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

diff_cont:
  ros__parameters:

    publish_rate: 30.0

    base_frame_id: base_link

    left_wheel_names: ['left_wheel_joint']
    right_wheel_names: ['right_wheel_joint']
    wheel_separation: 0.335
    wheel_radius: 0.06

    use_stamped_vel: false
    enable_odom_tf: false

    # open_loop: false    

    # wheels_per_side: x
    # wheel_separation_multiplier: x
    # left_wheel_radius_multiplier: x
    # right_wheel_radius_multiplier: x

    # odom_frame_id: x
    # pose_covariance_diagonal: x
    # twist_covariance_diagonal: x
    # open_loop: x

    # cmd_vel_timeout: x
    # publish_limited_velocity: x
    # velocity_rolling_window_size: x
    

    # linear.x.has_velocity_limits: false
    # linear.x.has_acceleration_limits: false
    # linear.x.has_jerk_limits: false
    # linear.x.max_velocity: NAN
    # linear.x.min_velocity: NAN
    # linear.x.max_acceleration: NAN
    # linear.x.min_acceleration: NAN
    # linear.x.max_jerk: NAN
    # linear.x.min_jerk: NAN

    # angular.z.has_velocity_limits: false
    # angular.z.has_acceleration_limits: false
    # angular.z.has_jerk_limits: false
    # angular.z.max_velocity: NAN
    # angular.z.min_velocity: NAN
    # angular.z.max_acceleration: NAN
    # angular.z.min_acceleration: NAN
    # angular.z.max_jerk: NAN
    # angular.z.min_jerk: NAN




# joint_broad:
#   ros__parameters:
```

launch file

```python
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node

from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

def generate_launch_description():


    # Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled

    package_name='robo2023'

    pkg_share = FindPackageShare(package=package_name).find(package_name)

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true', 'use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items()
    )

    twist_mux_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','twist_mux.yaml')
    twist_mux = Node(
            package="twist_mux",
            executable="twist_mux",
            parameters=[twist_mux_params],
            remappings=[('/cmd_vel_out','/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped')]
        )
    
    robot_localization_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/ekf.yaml') 

    # Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
             )

    start_robot_localization_cmd = Node(
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='ekf_node',
        name='ekf_filter_node',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[robot_localization_file_path, 
        {'use_sim_time': True}])

    # Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                        output='screen')

    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["diff_cont"],
    )

    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_broad"],
    )                    



    # Launch them all!
    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,
        twist_mux,
        gazebo,
        start_robot_localization_cmd,
        spawn_entity,
        diff_drive_spawner,
        joint_broad_spawner
    ])
```

rqt_graph
[image]

UPDATE : add ekf.yaml

```yaml
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:

        use_sim_time: true

        
# The frequency, in Hz, at which the filter will output a position estimate. Note that the filter will not begin
# computation until it receives at least one message from one of the inputs. It will then run continuously at the
# frequency specified here, regardless of whether it receives more measurements. Defaults to 30 if unspecified.
        frequency: 30.0

# The period, in seconds, after which we consider a sensor to have timed out. In this event, we carry out a predict
# cycle on the EKF without correcting it. This parameter can be thought of as the minimum frequency with which the
# filter will generate new output. Defaults to 1 / frequency if not specified.
        sensor_timeout: 0.1

# ekf_localization_node and ukf_localization_node both use a 3D omnidirectional motion model. If this parameter is
# set to true, no 3D information will be used in your state estimate. Use this if you are operating in a planar
# environment and want to ignore the effect of small variations in the ground plane that might otherwise be detected
# by, for example, an IMU. Defaults to false if unspecified.
        two_d_mode: true

# Use this parameter to provide an offset to the transform generated by ekf_localization_node. This can be used for
# future dating the transform, which is required for interaction with some other packages. Defaults to 0.0 if
# unspecified.
        transform_time_offset: 0.0

# Use this parameter to provide specify how long the tf listener should wait for a transform to become available. 
# Defaults to 0.0 if unspecified.
        transform_timeout: 0.0

# If you're having trouble, try setting this to true, and then echo the /diagnostics_agg topic to see if the node is
# unhappy with any settings or data.
        print_diagnostics: true

# Debug settings. Not for the faint of heart. Outputs a ludicrous amount of information to the file specified by
# debug_out_file. I hope you like matrices! Please note that setting this to true will have strongly deleterious
# effects on the performance of the node. Defaults to false if unspecified.
        debug: false

# Defaults to "robot_localization_debug.txt" if unspecified. Please specify the full path.
        debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt

# Whether to broadcast the transformation over the /tf topic. Defaults to true if unspecified.
        publish_tf: true

# Whether to publish the acceleration state. Defaults to false if unspecified.
        publish_acceleration: false

# If the filter sees a jump back in time, the filter is reset (convenient for testing with rosbags!)
        reset_on_time_jump: true

# REP-105 (http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) specifies four principal coordinate frames: base_link, odom, map, and
# earth. base_link is the coordinate frame that is affixed to the robot. Both odom and map are world-fixed frames.
# The robot's position in the odom frame will drift over time, but is accurate in the short term and should be
# continuous. The odom frame is therefore the best frame for executing local motion plans. The map frame, like the odom
# frame, is a world-fixed coordinate frame, and while it contains the most globally accurate position estimate for your
# robot, it is subject to discrete jumps, e.g., due to the fusion of GPS data or a correction from a map-based
# localization node. The earth frame is used to relate multiple map frames by giving them a common reference frame.
# ekf_localization_node and ukf_localization_node are not concerned with the earth frame.
# Here is how to use the following settings:
# 1. Set the map_frame, odom_frame, and base_link frames to the appropriate frame names for your system.
#     1a. If your system does not have a map_frame, just remove it, and make sure "world_frame" is set to the value of
#         odom_frame.
# 2. If you are fusing continuous position data such as wheel encoder odometry, visual odometry, or IMU data, set
#   "world_frame" to your odom_frame value. This is the default behavior for robot_localization's state estimation nodes.
# 3. If you are fusing global absolute position data that is subject to discrete jumps (e.g., GPS or position updates
# from landmark observations) then:
#     3a. Set your "world_frame" to your map_frame value
#     3b. MAKE SURE something else is generating the odom->base_link transform. Note that this can even be another state
#         estimation node from robot_localization! However, that instance should *not* fuse the global data.
        #map_frame: map                   # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom                 # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
        world_frame: odom                # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

# The filter accepts an arbitrary number of inputs from each input message type (nav_msgs/Odometry,
# geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped, geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped,
# sensor_msgs/Imu). To add an input, simply append the next number in the sequence to its "base" name, e.g., odom0,
# odom1, twist0, twist1, imu0, imu1, imu2, etc. The value should be the topic name. These parameters obviously have no
# default values, and must be specified.
        odom0: diff_cont/odom

# Each sensor reading updates some or all of the filter's state. These options give you greater control over which
# values from each measurement are fed to the filter. For example, if you have an odometry message as input, but only
# want to use its Z position value, then set the entire vector to false, except for the third entry. The order of the
# values is x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Note that not some message types
# do not provide some of the state variables estimated by the filter. For example, a TwistWithCovarianceStamped message
# has no pose information, so the first six values would be meaningless in that case. Each vector defaults to all false
# if unspecified, effectively making this parameter required for each sensor.
        odom0_config: [true, true, true,
                       false, false, false,
                       true,  true,  true,
                       false, false, true,
                       false, false, false]

        #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
        #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
        #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
        #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
        #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]

# If you have high-frequency data or are running with a low frequency parameter value, then you may want to increase
# the size of the subscription queue so that more measurements are fused.
        odom0_queue_size: 2

# [ADVANCED] Large messages in ROS can exhibit strange behavior when they arrive at a high frequency. This is a result
# of Nagle's algorithm. This option tells the ROS subscriber to use the tcpNoDelay option, which disables Nagle's
# algorithm.
        odom0_nodelay: false

# [ADVANCED] When measuring one pose variable with two sensors, a situation can arise in which both sensors under-
# report their covariances. This can lead to the filter rapidly jumping back and forth between each measurement as they
# arrive. In these cases, it often makes sense to (a) correct the measurement covariances, or (b) if velocity is also
# measured by one of the sensors, let one sensor measure pose, and the other velocity. However, doing (a) or (b) isn't
# always feasible, and so we expose the differential parameter. When differential mode is enabled, all absolute pose
# data is converted to velocity data by differentiating the absolute pose measurements. These velocities are then
# integrated as usual. NOTE: this only applies to sensors that provide pose measurements; setting differential to true
# for twist measurements has no effect.
        odom0_differential: false

# [ADVANCED] When the node starts, if this parameter is true, then the first measurement is treated as a "zero point"
# for all future measurements. While you can achieve the same effect with the differential paremeter, the key
# difference is that the relative parameter doesn't cause the measurement to be converted to a velocity before
# integrating it. If you simply want your measurements to start at 0 for a given sensor, set this to true.
        odom0_relative: false

# [ADVANCED] If your data is subject to outliers, use these threshold settings, expressed as Mahalanobis distances, to
# control how far away from the current vehicle state a sensor measurement is permitted to be. Each defaults to
# numeric_limits<double>::max() if unspecified. It is strongly recommended that these parameters be removed if not
# required. Data is specified at the level of pose and twist variables, rather than for each variable in isolation.
# For messages that have both pose and twist data, the parameter specifies to which part of the message we are applying
# the thresholds.
        odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
        odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0

        imu0: imu/data
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                      true,  true,  true,
                      false, false, false,
                      true,  true,  true,
                      true,  true,  true]

        #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
        #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
        #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
        #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
        #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]
        
        imu0_nodelay: false
        imu0_differential: false
        imu0_relative: true
        imu0_queue_size: 7
        imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
        imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
        imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #

# [ADVANCED] Some IMUs automatically remove acceleration due to gravity, and others don't. If yours doesn't, please set
# this to true, and *make sure* your data conforms to REP-103, specifically, that the data is in ENU frame.
        imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

# [ADVANCED]  The EKF and UKF models follow a standard predict/correct cycle. During prediction, if there is no
# acceleration reference, the velocity at time t+1 is simply predicted to be the same as the velocity at time t. During
# correction, this predicted value is fused with the measured value to produce the new velocity estimate. This can be
# problematic, as the final velocity will effectively be a weighted average of the old velocity and the new one. When
# this velocity is the integrated into a new pose, the result can be sluggish covergence. This effect is especially
# noticeable with LIDAR data during rotations. To get around it, users can try inflating the process_noise_covariance
# for the velocity variable in question, or decrease the  variance of the variable in question in the measurement
# itself. In addition, users can also take advantage of the control command being issued to the robot at the time we
# make the prediction. If control is used, it will get converted into an acceleration term, which will be used during
# predicition. Note that if an acceleration measurement for the variable in question is available from one of the
# inputs, the control term will be ignored.
# Whether or not we use the control input during predicition. Defaults to false.
        use_control: false
# Whether the input (assumed to be cmd_vel) is a geometry_msgs/Twist or geometry_msgs/TwistStamped message. Defaults to
# false.
        stamped_control: false
# The last issued control command will be used in prediction for this period. Defaults to 0.2.
        control_timeout: 0.2
# Which velocities are being controlled. Order is vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw.
        control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
# Places limits on how large the acceleration term will be. Should match your robot's kinematics.
        acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
# Acceleration and deceleration limits are not always the same for robots.
        deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
# If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its acceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these
# gains
        acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
# If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its deceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these
# gains
        deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
# [ADVANCED] The process noise covariance matrix can be difficult to tune, and can vary for each application, so it is
# exposed as a configuration parameter. This matrix represents the noise we add to the total error after each
# prediction step. The better the omnidirectional motion model matches your system, the smaller these values can be.
# However, if users find that a given variable is slow to converge, one approach is to increase the
# process_noise_covariance diagonal value for the variable in question, which will cause the filter's predicted error
# to be larger, which will cause the filter to trust the incoming measurement more during correction. The values are
# ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the matrix below if
# unspecified.
        process_noise_covariance: [0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025,   0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]
# [ADVANCED] This represents the initial value for the state estimate error covariance matrix. Setting a diagonal
# value (variance) to a large value will result in rapid convergence for initial measurements of the variable in
# question. Users should take care not to use large values for variables that will not be measured directly. The values
# are ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the matrix below
#if unspecified.
        initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                                      0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of ros2_controllers are you using?

rqt_graph also shows that robot_state_publisher publishs tf, are you sure it is coming from diff_drive_controller?

My suggestion: Try to remap the topics in the launch file and introspect with `ros2 topic info tf`

Regarding rviz and odometry: This is a completely different topic/information. The robot model display uses tf, odometry is a different display type showing the calculated position+velocity by arrows. The two odometry topics are namespaced acc. to your graph, but have a look with `ros2 topic info /diff_cont/odom` or `ros2 topic info /odometry/filtered`

Comment: Seconding this. If it's the rviz display that's jumping back and forth, then my guess is you are attempting to fuse absolute pose data from two input sources in your EKF and it's jumping back and forth between them. I'd update the question with your EKF config and sample sensor messages for each input.

Comment: I'm using ros-humble-ros2-controllers. and yeah I'm pretty sure that even after set enable_odom_tf: false , /diff_cont still publish to /tf after I run ros2 topic info -v /tf.

Also update ekf.yaml file with /imu/data message is sensor_msgs/msg/Imu
/diff_cont/odom is nav_msgs/msg/Odometry.

Comment: I try to remap ekf_node to /tf_ekf and turn out that /tf publishers are 2 from robot_state_publisher and 1 from /diff_cont. If I misunderstand or provide not enough information please let me know.

Comment: The diff_drive_controller will register a publisher for /tf in any case, but shouldn't publish topics to it if `enable_odom_tf==false`. Are you sure it publishes?

Comment: You're right and seems like all of this is my misunderstand concepts. Yeah diff_cont doesn't publish any thing. Thank you so much.